# PHP DOMDocument load XML timeout

Tags: php, xml, load, xml-parsing, domdocument

I generate XML dynamically using this:

```
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$domtree -> formatOutput = true;
$xmlRoot = $domtree -> createElement("theparent");
bla..bla..bla..
echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

I load generated xml from PHP using this

```
$f = "http://localhost/myapp/xml/products.php"; //full url path
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($f)
```

bla..bla..bla..

but it tooks long execution and I get this error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://localhost/myapp/xml/products.php) [function.load]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in F:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\loader\loadxml.php on line 14

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in F:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\loader\loadxml.php on line 16
```

I ever done this load XML method using same way, but why in this app I get that error? is there any special xampp or php setting? or my code is incorrect?

thank you :)

Comment: btw, I'm using PHP Version 5.0.5

Comment: Try using absolute path to the file's path, BTW shouldn't it be products`.xml` ? and try the next solution: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php#91384

Comment: no, it's products.php. I generated XML dynamicaly and content-type is text/xml. btw, thank you for the link. I try it..

Comment: @OfirBaruch yep..it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try `if(!file_exists($f)) echo "the file doesn't exists";`

Comment: yes you are right, why my file is doesn't exists? but if I access it directly to browser address bar it works and exists ??? *more confusing #-O *

Comment: 1.Try using path like: `/xml/products.php` (related to your loadxml.php file of course) , 2.Is Your server on `safe mode`?

Comment: if I don't use full path, I get error again like this: DOMDocument::load() [function.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in file... 2. I use localhost and it is in normal mode

Answer (score 0):

Your script is attempting to download the php file, not fetch the XML output. Output to an XML file on the server and fetch that instead, or create a web service that returns the XML, then use something like cURL to use it.

Comment: yes I have done that too. I generate too products.xml and load like above and it still doesn't work :(. but I tried the comment above if(!file_exists($f)) echo "the file doesn't exists", yes why my file doesn't exists??

Comment: Oh. `allow_url_open` disabled? (But that would throw a warning anyway). Incorrect path? Strict file permissions?

Comment: allow_url_open is On or has 1 value in php.ini or phpinfo().. OMG what's wrong with my php #O